# Bibliography is not showing up in Overleaf

Tags: latex, overleaf

I am using this template in my overleaf Report:

https://www.overleaf.com/project/60c75f5e234ec24080f0ea6a

If link is not accesible here is the code:

```
\documentclass [11pt]{article}

\title{Fuel Cell Technology\\\medskip An Annotated Bibliography}
\author{Titus Barik (titus@barik.net)\\Georgia Institute of Technology}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEannot}
\bibliography{annot}
\end{document}
```

`annot.bib file`

```
@InProceedings{Wang99,
  author    = {Yanqing Wang and Christine MacKenzie},
  title     = {Object Manipulation in Virtual Environments: Relative Size Matters},
  booktitle = {Proc. CHI'99},
  year      = {1999},
  month     = {May},
  annote    = {.}
}

%%

@InProceedings{Feiner93,
  author    = {S. Feiner and B. MacIntyre and M. Haupt and E. Solomon},
  title     = {Windows on the World: {2D} Windows for {3D} Augmented Reality},
  booktitle = {Proc. UIST'93},
  year      = {1993},
  pages     = {145-155},
  annote    = {I.}
}
```

I am new to latex coding but fixed most of the bugs but stuck at printing the references in the final page of my report.

I took the contents `annot.bib` file and pasted in my overleaf report as follows:

```
\bibliography{annot}
\end{document}
```

Output is only showing `References` as heading and no references inside.

My code:

https://www.overleaf.com/read/wnhgtcggncff

My file:

```
    \documentclass[fleqn,10pt]{olplainarticle}
% Use option lineno for line numbers 
\usepackage{graphics}
%\newcommand{\newpar}{\vspace{.2in}\noindent}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\let\oldhref\href
\renewcommand{\href}[2]{\oldhref{#1}{\bfseries#2}}


\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{IIT Hyderabad Logo_Final Design.jpeg}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
ABC
\end{center}


\section*{abstract}



\section*{Introduction}


\section*{Methods and Materials}


\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l|r}
 \\\hline
 \\
A & B
\end{tabular}
\caption{\label{tab:widgets}An exploration table.}
\end{table}


\section*{AL}
%\label{sec:examples}
%\noindent
    


……….



%\subsection*{Figures and Tables}

\begin{figure}
\centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{download.png}
    \caption{Diagram illustrating the three main active learning scenarios.}
    \label{fig:view}

 
\end{figure}


\section*{DP}



\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{Picture 1.png}
    \caption{Dealing with lack of annotated data}
    \label{fig:view}

    \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{Picture 2.png}
    \caption{Pipeline}
    \label{fig:view}
\end{figure}



\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{dp.png}
    \caption{Architecture Diagram}
    \label{fig:view}
\end{figure}


\section*{Acknowledgments}
\bibliography{annot}

\end{document}
```

I am not getting `References` in Output and getting warning `You have used the same label more than once. Check that each \label{...} labels only one item.`

Comment: The link to your template gives a permission denied error.

Comment: Can you make a [mre] that does not rely one files we don't have access to?

Comment: About the second warning: you are using `fig:view` about 4 times. Use a unique label for each caption.

Comment: How to add unique label and remove fig:view single.? Can you show?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I have edited the question.

Comment: Do you have `IEEEannot.bst` in your overleaf folder?

Comment: No i do not have it.

Comment: To solve the label problem, choose a different word for each label. For example the first figure could have `\label{fig:view}`, the next one then `\label{fig:tree}`, then  `\label{fig:flower}`, they just need to be different

Comment: Then you must add the .bst file to your project, e.g. from https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ieeeannot It is a special style which is not installed by default.

Comment: Added. Getting error BibTeX: Illegal, another \bibstyle command : \bibstyle : {IEEEannot}

Comment: This works: https://www.overleaf.com/read/dwmxxpkdbtqc

Comment: \nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEannot}
\bibliography{annot}.         BibTeX: Illegal, another \bibstyle command : \bibstyle : {IEEEannot}

Comment: not sure what you want to tell with this comment

Comment: Still getting this error

Comment: Can you turn on link sharing in your overleaf project so we can see the actual code your are using?

Comment: So about the final code block in your question: I don't have the documentclass, no idea if it actually works, but you need `\usepackage{graphicx}` and not `\usepackage{graphics}` if you are using `width=...` syntax and don't use `_` in file names,

Comment: Here is a repaired version of the final code block: https://www.overleaf.com/read/ymhhwjcbrgwn

Comment: I have shared the code online ... please check https://www.overleaf.com/read/wnhgtcggncff

Comment: Thanks for sharing! Your documentclass has `\bibliographystyle{apalike}` in line 44, so you can't select another style later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your document class already selects a bibliography style, which you can't change afterwards. Two workarounds:

- use the style your document class sets by removing `\bibliographystyle{IEEEannot}` from your code
- if you actually do need the other style, save `olplainarticle.cls` under a new name and change l.8 `\ProvidesClass{olplainarticle}[06/12/2015, v1.0]` to the new name, remove line 43/44 `\RequirePackage{natbib} \bibliographystyle{apalike}` from the new .cls file and then change `\documentclass{olplainarticle}` to the new name